# Universal Analytics cross domain tracking with multiple trackers

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

So i have Universal Analytics code with multiple trackers:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('create', 'UA-yyyyyyyy-y', 'auto', {'name': 'second'});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('second.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

How do i create Cross Domain tracking since UA-yyyyyyyy-y profile is used to gather info from 2 separete domains. With one tracker it is pretty simple:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-yyyyyyyy-y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['other-domain.com'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But what do i do wen i have 2 trackers, how do i set up cross domain tracking for this Universal Analytics profile: UA-yyyyyyyy-y? If you answer my question you will also answer a part of this question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126897/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-with-multiple-trackers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example with just a single tracker, you're missing the call to require the linker plugin. Without that it won't work. Perhaps that is the source of your issue.

Regardless, in analytics.js you can call any method on any tracker by simply prefixing the method name with the tracker name. You'll notice your first example already does this in the line `ga('second.send', 'pageview')`.

So, to implement auto-linking on both trackers you'd do something like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-yyyyyyyy-y', 'auto', {allowLinker: true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['other-domain.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'UA-yyyyyyyy-y', 'auto', {name: 'second', allowLinker: true});
ga('second.require', 'linker');
ga('second.linker:autoLink', ['other-domain.com'] );
ga('second.send', 'pageview');
```

Notice the `second.` prefix on all the method calls in the second block which corresponds to the name "second" that I gave the tracker.

For more information on the auto-linker plugin, check out this resource:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink

And for more information on the various methods and method signatures, here is the guide:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference

Comment: Thanks for you're help. I think there is one sintax error in this line: ga('create', 'UA-yyyyyyyy-y', 'auto', {name: 'second', allowLinker': true}); One apostrophe is missing